# Enable/Disable torch with DataScannerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, vision, visionkit, datascannerviewcontroller

On iOS16, I try to use the `DataScannerViewController` (for barcode reading) to remplace old way with Vision but when I enable the torch, `DataScannerViewController` is freezing...

The code to enable/disable torch :

```
guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video), device.hasTorch else { return }

do {
    try device.lockForConfiguration()
    device.torchMode = device.isTorchActive ? .off : .on
    device.unlockForConfiguration()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

(This code is working well with Vision)

Thanks a lot

Comment: hmm... Vision is not the "old way", and DataScannerViewController is just a convenience on top of Vision and AVFoundation (so it's easier for people who don't have anything to implement it). So if you already have something implemented with Vision directly., it makes 0 sense for you to use DataScannerViewController

Comment: It's make sense for sustainability (less code, readability, async/await, Actors), this is why I said "old way" ;-)

Comment: Not really, unless you have a plain vanilla use case with no customization (which is clearly not the case). Vision is around for what... 8 years or so? how it's not sustainable? And nothing prevents you from properly using async/await or actors with vision.

Comment: @neilaur does this code not lock up your AV session? when using this code, I can no longer scan.

Comment: I have the same problem (on recent phones) and I did not find a solution. If you find something, i'm interesting.

Comment: Also with the same problem here, if anyone knows, please help!

Comment: I ran into the same issue today when testing on an iPhone. The interesting thing is that when I tested on an iPad the torch came on and off without freezing the DataScannerViewController. They both run the same SwiftUI code with no differences in how the sheet is handled in iOS or iPad OS. I’ll do some more testing tomorrow and see if I can reproduce in a sample app.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the example on this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297812/avcapturesession-freezes-when-torch-is-turned-on) to configure the full AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession and then use that to activate the torch. So far the issue seems to be resolved.

```
let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInTripleCamera, .builtInDualWideCamera, .builtInUltraWideCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera, .builtInTrueDepthCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: cameraPosition)
```

Comment: This isn’t working in iOS17 as of 17.0.2 at least. The camera will freeze when the torch is activated and I haven’t found a way around it yet.

Comment: Getting the device via `AVCaptureDevice.userPreferredCamera` seems to work on iOS 17.